# Cython Float Division Error: Zero Division (Numbers too big or too small?)

Tags: cython, divide-by-zero

I have a really odd zero division error. I have the code

```
from numpy import pi
cdef double a0 = 0.02
cdef double c = 2.998e8
cdef double me = 9e-31
cdef double s = 50.0
cdef L = 800e-9
cdef q = 1.602e-19  
cdef double E1=(a0*c*me*s*L*sqrt(pi))/(q*(1.602*10**(-13))*sqrt(2.0)) #some code
```

Yet it gives a

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division
```

despite the fact that they are all doubles. Are these numbers too big or two small for the double data type? I tested this calculation in the python shell and there is no error.
Thanks in advance for the help and/or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cdef double E1=(a0*c*me*s*L*sqrt(pi))/(q*(1.602*10**(-13))*sqrt(2.0)) #some code
```

to

```
cdef double E1=(a0*c*me*s*L*sqrt(pi))/(q*(1.602*10.0**(-13))*sqrt(2.0)) #some code
```

i.e change 10 to 10.0